# Sparse Group lasso by CVX MATLAB package

Tags: matlab, cvx

Does anyone know how can I implement sparse group lasso using CVX, convex optimization  package in MATLAB?

I don't know how can I describe the formula as CVX prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something [here](https://github.com/axsauze/sparse/blob/master/functions/SparseGroupLasso.m)

I decided to share it!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use CVX?  Inria has a sparse modeling package called [Spams](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr) written in Matlab, R, and Python.  If you want a group lasso regularizer look at the documentation in the [proximal toolbox](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/doc/html/doc_spams006.html#sec25) under mexproximalFlat.  There are some examples as well.  I use the python spams package quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

(**correction**: both support different group sizes. the example from **nfs** supports different group sizes by using additional constraints.)

Refer to this webpage for an example given by **nfs**:
http://ask.cvxr.com/t/formulating-sparse-group-lasso-in-cvx/793/4
However this example seems not allow different group sizes. You may refer to the following example
(The formula used is Eq.3 in *Simon, Noah, and Robert Tibshirani. "Standardization and the group lasso penalty." Statistica Sinica 22.3 (2012): 983.*)

```
% Refer to Eq. (3) in /Simon, Noah, and Robert Tibshirani. 
%    "Standardization and the group lasso penalty." 
%    Statistica Sinica 22.3 (2012): 983./

% Note that group LASSO allows different group sizes
N = 64; m = 3;   
rho = [2; 4; 6];  % group sizes
n = sum(rho); % num of total parameters
X = rand(N,n);   % X = [X1, X2, ..., X_m]
y = rand(N,1);
lambda = 1;

IndexM = [1, 2; 3, 6; 7, 12];  % indexes of elements in each group
cvx_begin
    % w = [beta1'; beta2'; ...; beta_m']
    variable w(n)    
    expression ws(m)
    for i = 1:m
        ws(i) = norm(w(IndexM(i,1):IndexM(i,2)),2);
    end

    minimize( norm(y-X*w, 2) +  lambda*(sqrt(rho)' * ws) )
cvx_end

% get beta_i, i.e. i-th beta corresponding to i-th group
% e.g. 
i = 2;
beta_i = w(IndexM(i,1):IndexM(i,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe CVX cannot easily handle the group norm in SGL, unless you hard-code the group norm for each dataset. If u are using Matlab, you can use [SLEP toolbox](http://www.yelab.net/software/SLEP/).