# Sample Code for using Sparse Lasso Group in SPAMS

Tags: python, machine-learning

I found [Sparse Group lasso by CVX MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264607/sparse-group-lasso-by-cvx-matlab-package) and [SPAMS](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/) was mentioned in the response. Can someone share some sample codes, preferably python, for using Sparse Group lasso in SPAMS?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just implement this in `cvxpy`? You mentioned in your other post that you didn't know how to formulate the problem in `cvx`. It looks straight-forward. Is it not convex?

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the information on cvxpy. Is this the one? - http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/. I didn't post the question in other thread. The author found sparse lasso group code in MATLAB that I need to translate into Python. It looks like straightforward minimization/convex problem. If there is a library that I can use, I would like to use it. Do you know any sample code for SPAMS? The worst case is I implement it myself. Thanks!